# What are the temperature and top_p values used on chat.openai.com?

Tags: chatgpt, openai

What are the temperature and top_p values used on https://chat.openai.com/? I know that the temperature and top_p values with the [openai.com API](https://platform.openai.com/docs/api-reference/chat/create) both [default to 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iSUE.png) for chat completion, but I don't know if https://chat.openai.com/ used these default values.